# Horizontally adjust caption position in subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am using the `subfigure` package to have a figure with multiple plots and individual captions for all subfigures. Now, some of the figures have some axes with labels etc such that the caption is centered above the subfigure, but not centered above the plotting area which looks weird.

Is there any option to adjust the caption position, for example to move it to the right / left? I tried to add space via

```
\subfigure[\hspace{1cm}caption]{plot.pdf}
```

But this only leads to a gap between the label (a) and the caption (caption), and does not adjust the position of everything.

I would like to keep using the `subfigure` package, as I am using it widely in other parts of the document

Comment: Do you use `pgfplots` for your graphs? There would be a nice solution, if so.

Comment: Please note that the package `subfigure` is outdated since some time. You should switch to `subcaption` or alike. In order to solve your problem here (in case you did not make that `plot.pdf` by yourself) you could use the clip and trim commands from `graphicx`. Just introduce a little negative trim to the right side of your graphs and you will create some whitespace. Like this, the caption can stay where it is which is my absolute recommendation due to typographical consistency.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will do that then. I didn't know the subfigure package was out of date, in that case I will switch to subcaption I guess.